# Why can't add a dynamic label to a form in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 int cnt = 1;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Label addLabel(string s,int i)
    {



        System.Windows.Forms.Label l = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        l.Top = i;
        l.Name = ""+cnt;
        Controls.Add(l);
        cnt++;
        return l;


    }
```

When I run this code ,it tells me that the `Controls.Add(l)` takes invalid arguments and that it should take arguments of type Control .

Comment: Is this really asp.net ?

Comment: With [`Controls.Add(l)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you want to use [`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which inherits the `Control` class in the right namespace, not [`System.Windows.Forms.Label`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Pluto , ok now it works ,but do you have any idea on how to place it ,I want to add several labels one after the other but I want them in different lines not in the same line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw you put the "asp.net" tag onto your question, therefore I presume you're talking about an ASP.NET WebForm even if you don't specify that in your question.
In this case you should refer to the

```
System.Web.UI
```

namespace (not System.Windows.Forms), probably returning a LiteralControl in your case.
I hope this helps.